# How to avoid `missing expression` error in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to `count` number of each product by following `sql`

but I suffered following error..

`ORA-00936: Missing Expression`

Where is wrong with my sql.

If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

```
select t.customer,
       count(case when left(t.product,2)='AD' then 1 end) as A,
       count(case when left(t.product,1)='F' then 1 end) as B,
       count(case when left(t.product,1)='H' then 1 end) as C,
  from table t
  left join table2 t2
    on t.customer = t2.customer
 where t2.type='VLI'
 group by t.customer
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle doesn't have `LEFT()` function while MySQL does, use `SUBSTR()` instead. And remove the comma, which's typo , at the end of the fourth line

```
SELECT t.customer,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN SUBSTR(t.product, 1, 2) = 'AD' THEN
                1
             END) AS A,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN SUBSTR(t.product, 1, 1) = 'F' THEN
                1
             END) AS B,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN SUBSTR(t.product, 1, 1) = 'H' THEN
                1
             END) AS C
  FROM yourtable t
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t.customer = t2.customer
 WHERE t2.type = 'VLI'
 GROUP BY t.customer
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra comma in row `count(case when left(t.product,1)='H' then 1 end) as C,`.
Delete the last comma and this error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `LIKE`:

```
select t.customer,
       sum(case when t.product like 'AD%' then 1 else 0 end) as A,
       sum(case when t.product like 'F%' then 1 else 0 end) as B,
       sum(case when t.product like 'H%' then 1 else 0 end) as C
from table t left join
     table2 t2
     on t.customer = t2.customer and t2.type='VLI'
group by t.customer;
```

Notes:

- With `like`, you don't have to worry about an argument to a substring function matching the length of the matched string.  I learned about the issues of inconsistencies there a long, long, long time ago.
- I prefer `sum()` in this case over `count()`, but that is mostly aesthetic.
- You are using a `left join`, but filtering in the `where` clause.  This turns the join into an inner join.  Either change the `join` to inner join or move the condition to the `on` clause (as this does).